# How to add a WEB-INF folder to a git repository [ECLIPSE]

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, bitbucket, web-inf

I’ve created a Web Dynamic Project inside eclipse. It is linked to a repository
I’ve created with Bitbucket. This is the structure of the project:

> [image: structure]

As you can see WEB-INF folder is not included in the repository. I checked if
WEB-INF path was inside `.gitignore` file but this is not the case: it only
contains the build folder path. How can I add the WEB-INF folder to my
repository? This operation should add the same icon you can see on the other
folders of the project (the yellow disk).

Comment: After adding the Web-INF folder did you commit and Push after Adding to Index.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add a file to it. By default `WEB-INF` contains only files generated by Eclipse (`classes` and `lib`) and these are treated as ignored. If you add a file to it, EGit will let you add it to the repository. You can add an empty `.gitignore` file for instance. This is a common behavior of GIT, which ignores empty folders.

See below screenshots: empty dir `aaa` in `META-INF` seems to be ignored:

[image]

and a file in WEB-INF

[image]